# How to convert unicode string into list using pandas python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a unicode string like `[u'1,2,3,4']` and I want to convert this into `[1,2,3,4]`.

Example:

```
a=[u'1,2,3']
```

I get this from url values and I have to convert this format into:

```
a= [1,2,3]
```

It possible to compare this list values is present in particular column in a pandas dataframe?

Comment: how is this question related to `pandas`?

Comment: why this is possible question only

Comment: values are get from url and its convert to list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to test if your DataFrame contains the value

Suppose you have the array `[1, 2, 3]`, here's how you can test if a DataFrame contains a value

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]})
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for x in a:
...     print '{x} is in df'.format(x=x), any(df.a == x)
... 
1 is in df True
2 is in df False
3 is in df True
```

I'm using `df.<column_name> == <test_value>`, and wrapped it in `any()` that returns true if at least one match is found

### How to get the array

I split the string at `,` and then convert the result to an `int`

```
>>> [int(x) for x in [u'1,2,3'][0].split(',')]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Explanation

```
>>> a=[u'1,2,3'] 
>>> a
[u'1,2,3']          # This a list with one string: '1,2,3'
>>> a = a[0]
>>> a
u'1,2,3'            # I get the string from the list above
>>> a.split(',')    # I split this string on ','
[u'1', u'2', u'3']  # this is still a list of strings, 
                    # so I run int(x) on each element
                    # using a list comprehension below

>>> [int(x) for x in [u'1,2,3'][0].split(',')]
[1, 2, 3]           # the result you want
```

Comment: is it possible to compare this list values is present in particular column in dataframe???

Comment: @SaiRajesh updated with an example to test presence of the value in the df

Comment: but i have another doubt